# Verify connection via AS400

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400

My method must trying to connect to some other DB server. When I run my application on Linux Server - there was all OK. When I run it on Windows OS - I have `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`

```
 private boolean pingServer(String host) {
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    boolean successful;

    AS400 as400 = new AS400(host, username, password);
    SocketProperties socketProperties = as400.getSocketProperties();
    socketProperties.setLoginTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
    socketProperties.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);

    as400.setSocketProperties(socketProperties);
    try{
        successful = as400.validateSignon();
    } catch (AS400SecurityException e) {
        successful = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        successful = false;
    } catch (TransactionException e) {
        successful = false;
    }
    as400.disconnectAllServices();
    as400 = null;
    return successful;
}
```

Can anybody give me some advice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AS/400 connections use a lot of network ports which must be available to you.

Try disabling all firewalls between you and the server and try again.  This include the software firewall (may be part of the antivirus suite) on the Windows system

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have to set the socket properties.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I can't disable firewalls. Maybe you know another way, that can help me?

Comment: In that case you will need help from the AS/400 administrators.

Comment: You can find a list of the ports that JT400 needs here: http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/toolbox/faq/ports.html

Comment: The code worked when connecting from a Linux system. Therefore it makes more sense to assume the problem is somewhere on the Windows system, rather than what you refer to as the AS/400 (probably an IBM Power System)

Comment: @WarrenT "firewalls" include the software firewall (and antivirus) on the Windows system.  I can see this is not completely clear from the current wording.

Comment: Hi @KhrystynaMakar, did you manage to resolve this? I am facing an almost identical issue, the connections worked on a Linux server but am facing socket timeout problems on windows server. Appreciate any clues you could provide.